# How can I get all members whose EOT is set to expire in two weeks from today in WordPress configured with s2Member?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I plan on sending an email to users two weeks prior their membership EOT (end-of-term) in WordPress configured with [s2Member](http://www.s2member.com/framework/).  I plan on setting up a WordPress cron job for sending the actual email.

How can I query the database and get the correct users?

Comment: Impossible to answer this without knowledge of the s2Member part of the database schema.

Comment: The framework is free and is under GNU GPL v2 License.  I updated the question with a link to the s2Member framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$members = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "
         SELECT
         DISTINCT(u.ID),
         u.display_name name,
         u.user_email memberemail,
         um.meta_value eot
         FROM {$wpdb->users} u
         LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} um
         ON u.ID = um.user_id
         WHERE um.meta_key = 'wp_s2member_auto_eot_time'
        "), 
        ARRAY_A
    );

    foreach ($members as $member) {
        $round_numerator = 60 * 60 * 24;
        $rounded_time = ( round(strtotime('+13 days') / $round_numerator) * $round_numerator );
        $rounded_eot = ( round($member['eot'] / $round_numerator) * $round_numerator );
        if ($rounded_time !== $rounded_eot) {           
             unset($member);
        }
    }
```